# How can I work elegantly with raw JSON in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

New to Flutter/Dart. I have a code (simplified) that updates tasks in local repository (JSON based) based on a JSON API. I am trying to come up with logic to decide which tasks are new / updated and filter the List based on API accordingly, to be able to feed it to the repository (where it is updated in a batch transaction).

The (simplified) code below works, but seems very ugly to me. Is there a more elegant way of doing things than casting `List<dynamic>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
final List<dynamic> jsonData =
    json.decode(await apiWrapper.getTasks());
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> asListOfMap = jsonData.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
final tasksToUpdate = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.of(asListOfMap.where((element) {
  final task = Task.fromJson(element); // expects Map<String, dynamic>
  return (task != null && isTaskNewOrUpdated(task)));
}));
await taskRepository.batchInsertOrUpdate(tasksToUpdate); // expects List<Map<String, dynamic>>
```

Note: There is no need elsewhere to have `Task.toJson()`, that is why I want to work directly with what comes in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way looks better I guess

```dart
final tasks = json
    .decode(await apiWrapper.getTasks())
    .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>() as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
final tasksToUpdate = tasks.where((element) {
  final task = Task.fromJson(element); // expects Map<String, dynamic>
  return (task != null && isTaskNewOrUpdated(task));
}).toList();
await taskRepository
    .batchInsertOrUpdate(tasksToUpdate); // expects List<Map<String, dynamic>>
```

As far as I know there's no other way rather than casting `List<dynamic>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.